# Multiple tables with similar columns in a single DB

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, database-design

I am a web developer who's working on an Exam Generator project. Now I am stuck at one point.

I have one database with different tables. Four of these tables are somehow similar with their columns. I want to know what is the best practice for such thing.

**The similar tables I have are:**

> **Exam** (Used to store the exam name and the number of questions
> included in the exam).
>
> ID | ExamName | NumberofQuestions
>
> **UserExam** (Used to store the the exams availble for a user with his
> grade in each exam he took).
>
> ID | MemberID | ExamID | Grade
>
> **QuestionExam** (Used to store Question IDs included in each exam).
>
> ID | ExamID | QuestionID
>
> **UserSolution** (Used to store the user's answers for each exam he
> took).
>
> ID | MemberID | ExamID | QuestionID | UserAnswer

In the beginning, I wanted to merge the "Exam" table with the "QuestionExam" table, but then I asked myself if I merged them how would I have one ID for each exam? So I kept it as it is.

Comment: Your data structure looks correct.  `Exam`, `User`, and `Question` are all entities.  Your tables are junction tables for supporting many-to-many relationships.

Comment: Thank you Gordon for your confirmation. Appreciate your feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is correct with the tables. IF you want to be more desciriptive some practices say to value like Exam_ID, UserExam_ID, or UserSolution_ID that way you can distinguish between the two in a join. It all depends on personal preference. It is a little more writing but saves you from a headache in the long run.

Comment: Dear Palmer, really thank you for your confirmation. Actually my question was about the best practice and whether what I have done is correct or not. In the moment I am not worried about the description. Maybe later on I will start looking at it. Thanks again my dear :)